# How to validate a file upload field using Javascript/ google App script

Tags: javascript, validation

All

I have been stuck on my simple project for while now. I have created a web app code that allows others to upload their pdf file to my google folder but the problem that I could not figure out who to set specific file extension so other do not upload only accepted extension "pdf". inside my code, there is a function supposed to prevent any type of extension except for pdf but it did not work.

```
    <form>
        <input type="file" name="myFile" accept= "checkfile(sender);" id='file' >
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="button" id="submitBtn" value="Upload Files">
        <label id="resp"></label>
    </form>
    <script>
      document.getElementById('submitBtn').addEventListener('click',
        function(e){
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).uploadFiles(this.parentNode)
        })
        
        function onSuccess(data){
          document.getElementById('resp').innerHTML = "File Uploaded to the path " +data;
          
          
          function checkfile(sender) {
    
   var element=  document.getElementById('file')
   if ( sender !== '.pdf') {
   
   return sender.preventDefault(); 
   } else {
   
   return true; 
   }
}
        }
       
    </script>
```

code.gs

```
 function doGet() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form');
  return html.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}


function uploadFiles(data)
{
 var file = data.myFile;
 var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('...........');
 var createFile = folder.createFile(file);
 return createFile.getUrl();
}
```

Comment: in my function uploadFiles(data) I noticed that  I cannot open PDF when v8 chrome is enabled it looks the file is corrupted but when I disabled the v8 chrome it is working fine. Why is that happing? How to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

1. Use `accept` in `<input>`
   `<input type="file" accept=".pdf"/>`
2. Add server side validation for extension

```js
function uploadFiles(filename, data) {
  if (!!filename.match('^.*\.(pdf|PDF)$')) return false; // or throw error
}
```

Comment: this is not working with the script when I added it to upload files function, I created an error message with function onFailure(data){
                document.getElementById('err').innerHTML = ' file is not pdf';
        } by using withFailureHandler(onFailure) and it looks script does not read the pdf as a pdf extension

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to match the filename with just ".pdf" - You could try using regex to match to only the end of the file.

```
const regex = "^.+\.pdf$"
if (!sender.match(regex)) {
    return sender.preventDefault();
}
```